# Threads logic in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to resolve a university exercise. The class `AImpl` has a method `ma(B b)` that creates and runs two threads. These threads have to call `mb1()` and `mb2()` (they are simple methods that just print a text, so I didn't include them). The calling thread should then wait for `mb1()` to terminate before finishing.

My logic is:

The first thread enters and after finishing the execution of `b.mb1()` starts to `wait()` on the current object, releasing the mutex. Then the second thread runs and it does the same. When they are both waiting, the calling thread calls `notifyAll()` on the object, waking both of them. They execute `b.mb2()` and then terminate.

The problem is that when the first thread starts waiting with `object.wait()`, the control flow doesn't return on the calling thread and the program enters in a deadlock.

Where is my logic flawed?

```
public class AImpl{
    public static Object object = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BImpl b = new BImpl();
        AImpl.ma(b);
    }

    public static void ma(B b) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                b.mb1();

                synchronized(object){
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                b.mb2();

                System.out.println("Thread finished");
            }
        };

        Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                b.mb1();

                synchronized(object){
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                b.mb2();

                System.out.println("Thread finished");
            }
        };
        thread.run();
        thread1.run();

        synchronized(object){
            object.notifyAll();
        }

        System.out.println("Program finished.");
    }
}
```

Comment: After investigating more, yes, using ```synchronization``` and its ```methods``` is the way my teacher wants the assignment to be done.

Comment: Based on the comment you just deleted, I could see that `join` would not be able to accomplish it. What you should describe in your question is that the calling thread should be waiting for `mb1()` to complete in both of the other threads before it continues. By the way, you're using wait backwards. You want the calling thread to wait on the other threads, not the other way around. The reason I'm not writing a full answer is that I think I would get it wrong. Working with Java threads directly is very complicated, and there are libraries for simplifying it, so I'm super rusty on it.

Comment: I tried to do it as asked by the assignment (calling thread waiting for both threads to terminate ```mb1()```), but if I do that the threads calls ```notifyAll()``` before the calling threads gets to call the ```wait()```. This results again in a deadlock.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The lock is not held by the the thread while it's waiting. ["The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits..."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).

Comment: @DavidConrad Oh, right. Very rusty.

Comment: It seems like a deadlock to me. One in `wait()` and another one `notifyAll()`. Move `notifyAll()` above the line `b.mb2();` should fix the problem.

Comment: @Darkman, "Deadlock" means that two or more threads are all unable to make progress because each one of them is waiting for one of the others to do something. But, no thread will ever wait in a`notifyAll()` call. It always returns immediately. It wakes whatever threads are waiting at that moment, or it does absolutely nothing if no thread is waiting. When a thread gets stuck waiting for a notification that happened _before_ the thread started to wait, that usually is called, "lost notification."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well it might be the case. I just thought that the main thread gets stuck and unable to call `notifyAll()` hence a deadlock. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The notify/notifyAll methods tell the scheduler to notify one/all of the threads currently waiting on the lock that notify or notifyAll was called on. But if a thread hasn't started waiting yet then it doesn't get notified.

The solution is to introduce a condition variable that keeps wait from being called if the notifying has happened already. Define it in the same scope as your lock:

```
public static volatile boolean ready = false;
```

Then use it to guard the wait block, like this:

```
while (!ready) {
    object.wait();
}
```

The code calling notify/notifyAll needs to set the variable (it doesn't matter what order you do it in because the notification doesn't happen until the lock is released):

```
synchronized (object) {
    ready = true;
    object.notifyAll();
}
```

What happens:

If the waiting thread gets to the waiting part before the notifying thread does its notifying, then the waiting thread finds ready is false, so it enters the wait method, releases the lock, and stays there.  Then the notifying thread changes the flag to true and wakes up the waiting thread, which can leave the wait, reacquire the lock, and then leave the loop now that the flag is set.

But if the notifying thread does its notify before the other thread waits, that's ok, because the ready flag now prevents the thread from entering the wait, it can skip over it.

Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. At this point, I guess there's something wrong with my OS, Eclipse, or the JVM.

Comment: @BlueRyse: If you can provide a [mcve] you may get better answers. I understand you want to make the post short but that discourages people from helping when they don't have something they can run. And even if the suggested code doesn't work make sure you understand the point of avoiding races and not waiting if a notification isn't coming.